# Can Google App Engine's ImagesServiceFactory.getImagesService() be used in unit tests?

Tags: google-app-engine

I managed to get the code snippet below to run successfully in the development server, re-sizing image to 300x300 pixels as part of a web request.

However, I can't seem to run them in unit tests.

```
byte[] data = loadMyData();
OutputSettings format = new OutputSettings(ImagesService.OutputEncoding.JPEG);

Image resized = getImagesService().applyTransform(makeResize(300, 300, 0, 0), data, format);
```

The code above is throwing this exception in unit tests:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to read image
    at com.google.appengine.api.images.ImagesServiceImpl.convertApplicationException(ImagesServiceImpl.java:333)
    at com.google.appengine.api.images.ImagesServiceImpl.applyTransform(ImagesServiceImpl.java:86)
    at com.google.appengine.api.images.ImagesServiceImpl.applyTransform(ImagesServiceImpl.java:63)
```

Adding "LocalImagesServiceTestConfig" to the LocalServiceTestHelper does not make any difference.

Hope someone can confirm if we can actually use the getImagesService() to resize images in (Java) unit test.

Answer (score 0):

I might be missing something here, but couldn't you just have used the `get_serving_url` to make your resize? It's available for Java `imagesService.getServingUrl(blob)`
http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/images/ImagesService.html#getServingUrl%28com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.BlobKey,%20int,%20boolean%29
Regards,
Niklas

Comment: My intention is to upload the resized image to Amazon S3 through a separate task. Idea is to store resized bytes in blobstore as a temp.